# Targetting to multiple file format file (eg. pdf, doc, ppt)

Tags: android

In Iphone you can open pdf and other file format using WebView. so, why android is not having similar functionality, for online mode we can use 
"http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url= "

but in offline mode(without the internet access) how u'r going to do.
-- so, any how you are going to manage for pdf. file also then how you are going to target for other file format. It's really a biggest issue... I am struck with these things and aspect better solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are no JAR's that I'm aware of at the moment, but there is a project [here](http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/) that allows you to view PDF's, maybe you wanna give that a try?!

Answer (score 0):

In Android the only way is using Intent and set the setContentType for the particular file format which will redirect to the number of application support the file format.